# How to pass row index in javascript controller in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I am creating table row dynamically. I have to call javascript controller method from dynamically created ui:inputText using change="{!c.calculateCostAndPrice}" attribute. I need the current row Index from where method is being invoked. I have used aura-id to get the index but it works only for single row because, for multiple rows, aura-id will not be unique.

Component code-

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.PhaseLineItemWrapper}" var="item" indexVar="index">
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-accordian-sec" role="grid">
<tr class="slds-hint-parent" id ="{!index}">
    <td scope="row">
        <ui:inputText placeholder="Quantity"  value="{!item.QuantityOfItem}" class="slds-input" change="{!c.calculateCostAndPrice}" > 
    </td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Controller method-

```
calculateCostAndPrice : function(component,event,helper){
   var resultCmp = component.find("thisInput").get("v.value");
   console.log("resultCmp:::"+resultCmp);}
```

Comment: Can you try `event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.id` to get the Id from tr element?

Comment: @RatanPaul I am Getting 'Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined ' error.

Comment: Ajay check my answer hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an alternate solution for my problem. I can get index from the label attribute of ui:inputText.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.PhaseLineItemWrapper}" var="item" indexVar="index">
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-accordian-sec" role="grid">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" id="{!index}">
        <td scope="row">
            <ui:inputText placeholder="Quantity" label="{!index}" value="{!item.QuantityOfItem}" class="slds-input" change="{!c.calculateCostAndPrice}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller-

```
calculateCostAndPrice: function(component, event, helper) {
var indexvar = event.getSource().get("v.label");
console.log("indexvar:::" + indexvar);}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe, as of now it is not possible with `ui:inputText`. As a workaround, you can use HTML input element with a custom `HTML data-*` Attribute.

Component:

```
<aura:component>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-accordian-sec" role="grid">
        <aura:iteration items="1,2,3,4,5" var="item" indexVar="index">            
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent" id ="{!index}">
                <td scope="row"> 
                    <input data-row-index="{!index}" onchange="{!c.calculateCostAndPrice}" type="text" placeholder="Quantity"  value="{!item.QuantityOfItem}" class="slds-input" />
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </aura:iteration>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    calculateCostAndPrice : function(component, event, helper) {
        var target = event.target;
        var rowIndex = target.getAttribute("data-row-index");
        console.log("Row No : " + rowIndex);
    }
})
```

Comment: I had tried html input text earlier but it does not bind the input value with the wrapper list .That's why I am trying with UI input text.

Comment: What is your requirement? What will you do after getting the row no?

Comment: Have to do some calculations based on the input and show the result to user instantly.

Comment: After calculating the values I want to set the row on the same index in the wrapper with the calculated values ,where it was earlier.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I suggest you to use `event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.id` to get the id

```
<tr class="slds-hint-parent" id ="{!index}">
    <td scope="row" >
        <ui:inputText placeholder="Quantity"  value="{!item.QuantityOfItem}" 
                                 class="slds-input" change="{!c.calculateCostAndPrice}" > 
    </td>
</tr>
```

And Now In controller JS

Use

```
({
    calculateCostAndPrice : function(component, event, helper) {
        var rowIndex = event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.id ;
        console.log("Row No : " + rowIndex);
    }
})
```

Comment: I am still getting error "Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined" . But I have found alternate solution for this. I am able to get the index from label attribute of ui:inputText.

Comment: This is throwing an error as Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined